# How to append elements into Erlang list when the list size is unknown

Tags: erlang

How to append elements into Erlang `list` data type when size of the list is unknown.

Sample elements: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`.

The final list should be `L = [1,2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `list` in Erlang is dynamic-length, so you don't need to specify its final size in advance.

Also you can add new element to `list` this way:

```
List0 = [],
List1 = [4|List0],
List2 = [3|List1],
List3 = [2|List2],
List4 = [1|List3],
%% => List4 = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```